# Puppeteer failing to click a tag with same id second time after content changes

Tags: javascript, typescript, web-scraping, puppeteer

Working on Puppeteer to learn,so I am trying to form fill [this site](https://self-service.wits.ac.za/psc/csprodonl/UW_SELF_SERVICE/SA/c/VC_OA_LOGIN_MENU.VC_OA_LOGIN_FL.GBL)

**What script does**

- Goes to link above
- Click 'Create Temporary ID'
- Fill form
- Click continue
- Content changes
- Click continue again (Which is the same button with same ID value as the first 'Continue' button

**ISSUE**

- When I click on the button 'Continue' button for second time which is the same ID as the one that worked first it fails

**SCRIPT**

```
import tesseract from 'node-tesseract-ocr';
import Puppeteer from 'puppeteer';

const config = {
  lang: 'eng', // default
  oem: 3,
  psm: 13,
};

export class AutomationController {
  public async CreateProfile(data: any) {
    try {
      const _data = {
        nationality: 'BRA',
        id: '0508228690083',
        title: 'Mr',
        firstName: 'Shaun',
        middleName: 'Maxwell',
        surname: 'Smith',
        dob: '15062001',
        gender: 'M',
        email: 'shaun@gmail.com',
        countryCode: '+27',
        mobileNumber: '0832567890',
      };

      const browser = await Puppeteer.launch({ headless: false });
      const page = await browser.newPage();
      await page.goto(
        'https://self-service.wits.ac.za/psc/csprodonl/UW_SELF_SERVICE/SA/c/VC_OA_LOGIN_MENU.VC_OA_LOGIN_FL.GBL',
        { waitUntil: 'networkidle2', timeout: 0 }
      );

      // Click create temp id button
      await page.waitForSelector('#VC_OA_LOGIN_WRK_REGISTER');
      await page.click('#VC_OA_LOGIN_WRK_REGISTER');

      // Nationality field
      await page.waitForSelector('#VC_OA_LOGIN_WRK_COUNTRY');
      // await page.select('select[id="VC_OA_LOGIN_WRK_COUNTRY"]', 'AUS');

      // ID number field
      await page.waitForSelector('#VC_OA_LOGIN_WRK_NATIONAL_ID');
      const idInput = await page.$('#VC_OA_LOGIN_WRK_NATIONAL_ID');
      await idInput?.type(_data.id);
      await this.delay(4000);

      // Name Title field
      await page.waitForSelector('#VC_OA_LOGIN_WRK_NAME_PREFIX');
      await page.select(
        'select[id="VC_OA_LOGIN_WRK_NAME_PREFIX"]',
        _data.title
      );
      await this.delay(4000);

      // First name field
      await page.waitForSelector(
        '#win0divVC_OA_LOGIN_WRK_FIRST_NAMEctrl > #VC_OA_LOGIN_WRK_FIRST_NAME'
      ); // VC_OA_LOGIN_WRK_FIRST_NAME
      const firstNameInput = await page.$('#VC_OA_LOGIN_WRK_FIRST_NAME');
      await firstNameInput?.type(_data.firstName);
      await this.delay(4000);

      // Middle name field
      await page.waitForSelector('#VC_OA_LOGIN_WRK_MIDDLE_NAME');
      const middleNameInput = await page.$('#VC_OA_LOGIN_WRK_MIDDLE_NAME');
      await middleNameInput?.type(_data.middleName);
      await this.delay(4000);

      // Surname field
      await page.waitForSelector('#VC_OA_LOGIN_WRK_LAST_NAME');
      const surnameInput = await page.$('#VC_OA_LOGIN_WRK_LAST_NAME');
      await surnameInput?.type(_data.surname);
      await this.delay(4000);

      // Gender field
      await page.waitForSelector('#VC_OA_LOGIN_WRK_SEX');
      await page.select('select[id="VC_OA_LOGIN_WRK_SEX"]', _data.gender);
      await this.delay(4000);

      // Email field
      await page.waitForSelector(
        '#win0divVC_OA_LOGIN_WRK_EMAIL_ADDRctrl > #VC_OA_LOGIN_WRK_EMAIL_ADDR'
      );
      const emailInput = await page.$(
        '#win0divVC_OA_LOGIN_WRK_EMAIL_ADDRctrl > #VC_OA_LOGIN_WRK_EMAIL_ADDR'
      );
      await emailInput?.type(_data.email);
      await this.delay(4000);

      // Mobile number
      await page.waitForSelector('#VC_OA_LOGIN_WRK_VC_PHONE_CELL_SS');
      const mobileInput = await page.$('#VC_OA_LOGIN_WRK_VC_PHONE_CELL_SS');
      await mobileInput?.type(_data.mobileNumber);
      await this.delay(4000);

      await page.waitForSelector(
        '#win0divVC_SEC_WRK_HTML_AREA_02 > div > div > img'
      );

      // Bypass security check
      const imgs = await page.$$eval(
        '#win0divVC_SEC_WRK_HTML_AREA_02 > div > div > img',
        (imgs) => imgs.map((img) => img.getAttribute('src'))
      );
      const securityPassword = this.getCharacterAfterSecondUnderscore(imgs);

      await page.waitForSelector('#VC_OA_LOGIN_WRK_VC_SEC_CODE');
      const securityField = await page.$('#VC_OA_LOGIN_WRK_VC_SEC_CODE');
      await securityField?.type(securityPassword);

      await this.delay(4000);

      // Continue button
      await page.waitForSelector('#VC_OA_LOGIN_WRK_CONTINUE_PB');
      const continueBtn = await page.$('#VC_OA_LOGIN_WRK_CONTINUE_PB');
      await continueBtn.click();

      this.delay(5000);
      // TODO - HANDLE IF SECURITY CHECK FAILED

      //THIS THE BUTTON THAT FAILS TO CLICK SECOND TIME
      // CONFIRM Details button
      const confirmBtn = await page.$('#VC_OA_LOGIN_WRK_CONTINUE_PB'); 
      await confirmBtn.click();
      console.log(`Automation.controller - 136`, 'DONE');

      await this.delay(4000);
    } catch (error) {
      console.log(`Automation.controller - 137`, error);
    }
  }

  private delay(time) {
    return new Promise(function (resolve) {
      setTimeout(resolve, time);
    });
  }

  private getCharacterAfterSecondUnderscore(strings: string[]): string {
    const results: string[] = [];

    for (const string of strings) {
      const splittedString = string.split('_');
      results.push(splittedString[2]);
    }

    return results.join('');
  }
}
```

Comment: what's the error message on console? try capture console message with this: https://developer.chrome.com/docs/puppeteer/debugging/#capture-console-output

also it is advisable to use a full test suite that extends the basic functionality on top of puppeteer, such as cypress or playwright.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I tried this on my machine, and the answer to your problem is very simple, you simply forgot to add `await` keyword on the beginning of `this.delay(5000);` line:

```
...
      // Continue button
      await page.waitForSelector('#VC_OA_LOGIN_WRK_CONTINUE_PB');
      const continueBtn = await page.$('#VC_OA_LOGIN_WRK_CONTINUE_PB');
      await continueBtn.click();

      await this.delay(5000); // YOU FORGOT TO ADD await HERE
      // TODO - HANDLE IF SECURITY CHECK FAILED

      //THIS THE BUTTON THAT FAILS TO CLICK SECOND TIME
      // CONFIRM Details button
      const confirmBtn = await page.$('#VC_OA_LOGIN_WRK_CONTINUE_PB'); 
      await confirmBtn.click();
...
```